# street is not defined error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in Javascript and I have the following code:

```
let address = {
  street: 'Brighton',
  city: 'NY',
  zipcode: 121212,

  showAddress() {
    console.log(street + ' ' + city + ' ' + zipcode);// here is the issue I cannot understand why
  }
}

let address1 = address.showAddress();
```

The above code shows an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: street is not defined
>            at Object.showAddress

Comment: Why do you think it would be defined? :)

Comment: @Icepickle, as far as I understand there is scope chain concept. I used street, city and zipcode without this since if no variables are found inside showAddress method then JS engine will look for the variables outside the method. Is that correct? I hope you will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above the `{}` acts as Object literals not block.There are no variable named `street` in the scope of `showAddress()`.

You can access it using `this` which will refer to parent object. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to the object the method is called on

```js
let address = {
  street: 'Brighton',
  city: 'NY',
  zipcode: 121212,

  showAddress() {
    console.log(this.street + ' ' + this.city + ' ' + this.zipcode);// here is the issue I cannot understand why
  }
}

let address1 = address.showAddress();
```

Comment: thank you for your comment but why to use "this" since as I understood correctly there is scope chain concept which goes above if there is no local variable found.

Comment: @mirzhal `this` will refer to object inside object methods. And `{}` doesn't always create a scope.

Comment: @mirzhal See the updated post I have added a reference

Comment: @mirzhal Scope chains deal with variables. street, city, zipcode and showAddress are properties on the address object. You use this inside showAddress to refer to properties of the object that showAddress is part of. You could define `var street = 'abc';` above address where `this.street` would return 'Brighton' and without `this`, street would return 'abc'. [See Scope Chains on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Closure_Scope_Chain)

Comment: @Ceres, clear, on the point and just perfect answer. Thank you a lot:D